# ostream operator Overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class named Dollars as

```
    class Dollars
    {
    private:
            int dollars;
    public:
    Dollars(){}
    Dollars(int doll)
    {
            cout<<"in dollars cstr with one arg as int\n";
            dollars = doll;
    }
    Dollars(Cents c)
    {
            cout<<"Inside the constructor\n";
            dollars = c.getCents()/100;
    }
    int getDollars()
    {
            return dollars; 
    }
    operator int()
    {
            cout<<"Here\n";
            return (dollars*100);
    }

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, Dollars& dollar)
    {
            out<<"output from ostream in dollar is:"<<dollar.dollars<<endl;  
            return out;
    }
    };

    void printDollars(Dollars dollar)
    {
            cout<<"The value in dollars is "<< dollar<<endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
            Dollars d(2);
            printDollars(d);
            return 0;
    }
```

In the above code if I remove the overloaded ostream operator then it goes to

```
    operator int()
    {
            cout<<"Here\n";
            return (dollars*100);
    }
```

But on providing ostream overloading it does not go there.

My confusion

`Why isn't there any return type for operator int() function as far as my understanding says that all functions in C++ should have a return type or a void except the constructors.`

Instead of int can I provide some user defined datatype there ?

In what situation should I use this functionality ?

Answer (score 3):

This type of operator is called a [*conversion function*](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr385.htm). In your case, it converts from `Dollars` to `int`. That syntax is standard, you cannot specify a return type (you've already stated the type).

You can make conversion operators for custom types if you want. You could have:

```
operator Yen() { ... }
operator Euro() { ... }
```

Then an instance of `Dollar` could be converted implicitly to a `Yen` or `Euro`, using these functions, without needing a cast (or a constructor taking a `Dollar` in the `Yen` or `Euro` classes).

Example from the "C++03" standard (§12.3.2/2):

```
class X {
 // ...
 public:
 operator int();
};

void f(X a)
{
 int i = int(a);
 i = (int)a;
 i = a;
}
```

C++11 allows conversion functions to be marked as *explicit*. In that case, the conversion function is only considered during direct-initialization. (This is in general a good thing to do to avoid unexpected conversion, especially for fundamental types.) The example in the standard for that is (§12.3.2/2):

```
class Y { };
struct Z {
 explicit operator Y() const;
};

void h(Z z) {
 Y y1(z);     // OK: direct-initialization
 Y y2 = z;    // ill-formed: copy-initialization
 Y y3 = (Y)z; // OK: cast notation
}
```

(And C++11 states that conversion functions cannot be declared *static*.)

Comment: Note: C++11 allows for the `explicit` qualifier to be applied to conversion operators. I would recommend it.

Comment: +1 to @MatthieuM.'s suggestion and in case I am using c++03, I would most likely provide special functions rather than leave myself at implicit conversions happening all over the place.